# count() and find() not the same result

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

MongoDB 3.6.2

I have executed the script that has a count process from source collection and bulk insert to target collection by using forEach, and I declared a variable to count in forEach function to compare the count value from both steps but not match.

Count process

```
sourceCnt = db.sourceCollection.count({ xid : {$gte : ObjectId.fromDate(startDT), $lt : ObjectId.fromDate(endDT)}})
```

Bulk insert

```
var bulkIns = db.targetCollection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
db.sourceCollection.find({ xid : {$gte : ObjectId.fromDate(startDT), $lt : ObjectId.fromDate(endDT)}}).forEach(function(doc){ 
        bulkIns.insert(doc); 
        targetCnt++ 
})
```

The sourceCnt and targetCnt are not the same value.

Does anyone know or faced this similar problem?

Comment: One more thing, it looks like index data do not match the actual value, I have tried to backup and restore the number of the document that is the same as I bulk import.

Comment: where are you comparing both the numbers?

Comment: I'm comparing on Online database but data what I'm looking that is historical data.

Comment: i mean in your code.

Comment: I have created a js file to run by mongoshell.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to compare data from bulk insert result and bulk remove result instead of count result.

Comment: The bulk result shows the same as use count(), my understanding is count() function look in index information and shard cluster has chunk balancing event then some didn't be cleaned then no. of count() more than find().